Kitchenaid Double Oven Error F1E0 & F2E1
Model KODE500EBSO2 Electric. Installed in late 2021, has been working fine until 1 month ago.  When cooking meat in the top at 400 after about 1/2 hour there would be a quick double beep and the display shows ERR  F1E0 (display board), F2E1 (keyboard stuck).  This has been consistently happening.  I do not know if the bottom oven will duplicate the issue.  I use top for meats, pizza and frozen fried foods.  Oddly, it only happens when cooking meat at 400.
What do I need to replace?  Thank You!

The errors already told you what to replace—the control board and the key panel.

Hmm, ok thank you.
